# Get facebook posts from a group

Tags: java, android, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an android app and I want the app to get post from a facebook group which I am admin.How is that possible? I search online but I couldn't find a solution to the problem.

Thanks in advanceHey everoyne .I am developing an android app and I want the app to get post from a facebook group which I am admin.How is that possible? I search online but I couldn't find a solution to the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Prior to posting on StackOverflow, you should come up with, at least, a small snippet of code. Facebook has its own page for its APIs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ and for groups https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/common-uses#getting-group-posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you tried to do it with [facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/common-uses#getting-group-posts) and didn't find a way.

*You can perform a GET operation on the `/{group-id}/feed` edge to get posts on a Group.*

```
curl -i -X GET \ "https://graph.facebook.com/554611227955614/feed?limit=5&access_token=EAACEdEos0..."
```

Another solution would be to use a tool such as [chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/) and scrape the data. In other words to create a web scraper. In any case, I think, it is not allowed based on terms of use of Facebook. There must be a reason that there is no such functionality in their official API (if thats the case)